# Problem with migrating a model in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, migration

I run script/generate model query

edit query.rb in models..

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base #I even tried Migrations instead of Base
  def sef.up
    create table :queries do|t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :queries
  end
end
```

,run rake db:migrate.

and what I see in db is this:

```
mysql> desc queries;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| created_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| updated_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Where is the "name" field?

HELP ! Cheers !

Comment: Have you tried restarting your MySQL server to force information_schema to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `script/generate migration your_migration_name`.

**Edit #1**

I'll explain better:

Actually, when you run `script/generate model query` some files were created, including `models/query.rb` and `db/migrate/XXX_create_query.rb`. To create `queries` table you must edit the second file (`db/migrate/XXX_create_query.rb`) and insert the code you posted:

```
class CreateQueries < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
      create_table :queries do |t|
         t.string :name
      end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :queries
   end
end
```

and then run `rake db:migrate`.

**Edit #2**

As JacobM pointed, as you already run `rake db:migrate`, now you just need to create another migration

`script/generate migration add_name_column_to_queries_table`

edit the `db/migrate/XXX_add_name_column_to_queries_table.rb` file to insert your new `name` column and then run `rake db:migrate` again.

Answer (score 1):

Your data changes don't go in your model, they go in your migration.  When you ran script/generate model, in addition to the query.rb file in `models`, you also would have gotten an XXX_add_queries.rb file in `db/migrations`.  That's the file you need to edit to add another field.

However, if you've already run rake db:migrate, then you'll need to add a new migration to add your new field (`script/generate migration add_name_to_queries`), edit the new migration file, and run db:migrate again.